# Some help on how groupings actually work would be much appreciated

Tags: xslt-2.0

I'm trying to get my head around how the different grouping techniques work. What causes a group, how are each group defined, and how the key are formed for each group.

If I wanted to use "group-adjacent" to move all following siblings of a specific element name into the first of preceding sibling of a given type. Would this be doable? I know how I can do this with recursive templates, and to some extent with keys in xslt 1.0. But I cannot get the 2.0 groups to work for me.

Lets say that I want to move all fig elements into the first preceding para, given that there are no other kinds of elements in between the fig(s) and the preceding para element, in this simple xml.

```
<root>
    <first_lvl>
        <title>First heading</title>
        <para>First para under first heading</para>
        <para>Second para under first heading</para>
        <fig>fig1</fig>
        <fig>fig 2</fig>
        <table>Table A</table>
        <fig>fig 3</fig>
        <para>Third para under first heading</para>
        <para>Fourth para under first heading</para>
        <fig>fig4</fig>
    </first_lvl>
</root>
```

Desired result:

```
<root>
    <first_lvl>
        <title>First heading</title>
        <para>First para under first heading</para>
        <para>Second para under first heading
            <fig>fig1</fig>
            <fig>fig 2</fig>
        </para>
        <table>Table A</table>
        <fig>fig 3</fig>
        <para>Third para under first heading</para>
        <para>Fourth para under first heading
            <fig>fig4</fig>
        </para>
    </first_lvl>
</root>
```

How can I set a grouping up that takes care of every directly following fig element?

This doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template match=para[following-sibling::*[1][self::fig]]>
    <xsl:for-each-group select"folowing-sibling::*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::fig)">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" mode="move"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

And then I've added atemplate to build content for each fig inside the para, and one to ignore those figs when they appear later on in the processing.

No luck though.

I have no other values to group by, other that the fact that they are fig elements.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with a `group-starting-with` on those `para` followed by a `fig` and then inside use `group-adjacent` to identify only the first group of adjacent `fig`s. With the verbosity of XSLT that looks a bit convoluted but does the job as far as I have understood your requirements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="*[para and fig]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para[following-sibling::*[1][self::fig]]">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::para[following-sibling::*[1][self::fig]]">
                      <xsl:variable name="para-head" select="."/>
                      <xsl:for-each-group select="tail(current-group())" group-adjacent="boolean(self::fig)">
                          <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                  <xsl:copy select="$para-head">
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), current-group()"/>
                                  </xsl:copy>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                              </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:for-each-group>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKxh

I have taken the liberty to use XSLT 3 instead of 2 but you simply would have to spell out the identity transformation declared by the `xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"` and make sure you use

```
<xsl:element name="{name($para-head)}" namespace="{namespace-uri($para-head)}">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$para-head/node(), current-group()"/>
</xsl:element>
```

instead of the XSLT 3 only `xsl:copy` with a `select`:

```
                              <xsl:copy select="$para-head">
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="node(), current-group()"/>
                              </xsl:copy>
```

and instead of the XPath 3 `tail` function you use `subsequence` e.g.

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="*[para and fig]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-starting-with="para[following-sibling::*[1][self::fig]]">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::para[following-sibling::*[1][self::fig]]">
                      <xsl:variable name="para-head" select="."/>
                      <xsl:for-each-group select="subsequence(current-group(), 2)" group-adjacent="boolean(self::fig)">
                          <xsl:choose>
                              <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                                    <xsl:element name="{name($para-head)}" namespace="{namespace-uri($para-head)}">
                                      <xsl:apply-templates select="$para-head/node(), current-group()"/>
                                    </xsl:element>
                              </xsl:when>
                              <xsl:otherwise>
                                  <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                              </xsl:otherwise>
                          </xsl:choose>
                      </xsl:for-each-group>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/bFDb2BN

On the other hand, I am not sure whether an attempt not using `xsl:for-each-group` but rather a template matching `para[following-sibling::*[1][self::fig]]` and then consuming following sibling `fig`s (which can be done easily in XSLT 3 with `xsl:iterate`) is not more compact:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="para[following-sibling::*[1][self::fig]]">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
          <xsl:iterate select="following-sibling::*">
              <xsl:choose>
                  <xsl:when test="self::fig">
                      <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
                  </xsl:when>
                  <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:break/>
                  </xsl:otherwise>
              </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:iterate>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="fig[preceding-sibling::*[not(self::fig)][1][self::para]]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qVRKxh/3

Comment: Thank you for your quick response - much appreciated! I cannot get this to work in XMLSpy 2015, but I'm guessing it'll work better with Saxon. I'm trying to understand some parts of your solution; first of all, won't the select in the first for-each-group be relative to the context node, which will be a para or a fig?

Comment: The template matches on the parent element of the `para` and `fig` with `*[para and fig]`, so the `for-each-group select="*"` selects all child elements of the parent. In your case the parent is a `first_lvl` element, I was not sure whether that matters or is known, of course for the sample shown you could as well match explicitly on `match="first_lvl"`.

Comment: As for XSLT 2 and XML Spy, see the edit, I had used some other features not supported in that language (`tail`) and had not correctly implemented the `xsl:copy select` with `xsl:element`, now corrected, at least now works with an XSLT 2 processor although I don't have XMLSpy 2015 to test that particular processor.